# How to identify if a vector is a company or not from its ip address?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, localization, ip

I want to set up a system to identify the companies that connect to my web site from their ip address. But once I have the ip addresses of visitors to my site, how do I determine if the visitor is a company or not?

I retrieved the ip addresses of visitors in php

```
<?php
  function getIp(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
  }

  echo 'L adresse IP de l utilisateur est : '.getIp();
?>
```

Comment: For most of the world, this is not really a thing you can determine. Some *really large* companies have their own reserved block of IP addresses but for everyone else, at best, you *might* be able to resolve the IP address to an internet service provider. But whether their customer is a private person or a company is usually not public information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use : `gethostbyaddr` to get the DNS at least

```
<?php
  function getIp(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
  }

  echo 'L adresse IP de l utilisateur est : '.gethostbyaddr(getIp());
?>
```